# How does the number of categories in magento affect the performance?

Tags: performance, magento

Suppose we have 1000+ categories in magento. We are displaying them all in menu.

How does it affect the performance of the magento site?

Will there be any performance issue? If 1000 users are accessing the site concurrently

Answer (score 0):

First thing it will increase the HTML content on the page so obviously it will increase page size and thus load time.